# php generate json array then javascript display it out

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jsonp

i am working with JSON to send data to and from my server , but normally i work with sending one data at a time , now i want to :
retrieve all the rows from a table (mysql database) --> php put it in a JSON array + callback ---> javascript retrives it and display it out by looping through the data.

Here's my javascript(jQuery):

```
$.getJSON(domain_path + 'generate.php?table=' +  tbname + '&callback=?', function(data) {
});
```

As you can see this has table= the table name. which is for php to know which table to extract the data from.

But for the php part im not sure what to use to produce a JSONP array.

```
<?php
//connects to database
  include 'connect.php';

$tbname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['table']);
$callback = $_GET['callback'];

//some mysql commands
//after mysql commands
//i would use this to output data but this is only for one line of data.

    $output = array('error'=>'0');
    $out_string =  json_encode($output);
    echo $callback.'('.$out_string.');';    

?>
```

Mysql table structure:
Table name : users
name , link , email

How can i get all the rows from users table which contians their name , link and email and out it into a JSON array.
And how would i display it out using javascript(jquery)?
Is it using the `for` function in javascript

Comment: Are you sure you want JSON ***P*** output? From your Javascript call it looks like you want regular JSON.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is useless for escaping an object name, like a table or column name. If you quote it with backticks `\`` in the query, and error out if `strpos($_GET['table'], '\`') !== FALSE` then you should be fairly safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print out the JSON array in PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tbname."");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Catch and loop over result in jQuery:

```
    $.getJSON(domain_path + 'generate.php?table=' +  tbname + '&callback=?', function(data) {
         $.each(data, function() {
           $.each(this, function(k, v) {
           /// do stuff
           });
         });
    });
```

First each loop goes over your rows/objects; second loop goes over your attributes/columns.

Comment: @sm21guy Mistake, edited. And for function(k , v) check out documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: i meant loop the data out in jquery to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You approach using a named callback is all wrong, the callback functionality is already provided by jQuery - note that you have passed an empty function as the last argument to `getJSON()`? Well, that's your callback.

You want to do something like this:

PHP:

```
<?php

  //connects to database
  include 'connect.php';

  // mysql_real_escape_string() doesn't help, we need to do something like this:
  if (strpos($_GET['table'], '`') !== FALSE) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    exit;
  }

  // Build/make the query
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `{$_GET['table']}`";
  if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit;
  }

  // Fetch the returned data into an array of objects:
  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = (object) $row;
  }

  // Send the final data back as JSON
  exit(json_encode($output));
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON(domain_path + 'generate.php?table=' +  tbname, function(data, status, xhr) {
  // First check the response is a success:
  if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.log('Server responded with error code '+xhr.status);
    return;
  }
  // Now iterate over the data:
  $.each(data, function(key, item) {
    // Do something with the data here, for example:
    console.log('Name: '+item.name+', Link: '+item.link+', Email: '+item.email);
  });      
});
```

Comment: Yes. Javascript and PHP are both platform independent. Certain browsers provide non-standard bits of Javascript, and certain PHP functions don't work on certain OSes, but none of the above code uses anything that would give you an issue.

Comment: Thanks , just tried out the code , but im getting a `null` for the result of the php script.

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($data);`? And regarding the X-Domain - no, it won't work, but I prefer to do that server-side with cURL etc... is this option available to you?